# How to put the characters of a string in a specific order

Tags: python, string, list

I have a *list of positions*, like this:

```
a=[[1,0],[0, 2],[0, 4],[1,1],[0, 1],[0, 0],[1,3],[1,4],[1,2]]
```

I also have a *string*, for example this one:

```
string = "HELLOWORL"
```

And I want to put *each character of the string in the order 
of the list of positions*, in a matrix (where position[0] is the line and position[1] is the column),like this:

```
"string= WOELE
         HLLOR"
```

How do i do this?

Comment: your list of positions is the wrong way around, points normally go x-coordinate first.

Comment: I get an error on `a=[[1,0], [0, 2], ...` – "List indices must be integers, not tuple"

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Robert, the problem is that I'm a begginer and I have no idea how to this...

Answer (score 1):

You can use these functions to achieve that:

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to form tuples of elements in `s` and `a`

[`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to separate characters of line 1 and line 2

[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the characters of each line

```
a = [[1, 0], [0, 2], [0, 4], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2]]
s = "HELLOWORL"

first_line = sorted(filter(lambda i: i[0][0] == 0, zip(a, s)), key=lambda i: i[0][1])
second_line = sorted(filter(lambda i: i[0][0] == 1, zip(a, s)), key=lambda i: i[0][1])

word1 = ''.join(item[1] for item in first_line)
word2 = ''.join(item[1] for item in second_line)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> word1
'WOEL'
>>> word2
'HLLOR'
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done like this:

```
string = "HELLOWORL"

a = [[1,0],[0, 2],[0, 4],[1,1],[0, 1],[0, 0],[1,3],[1,4],[1,2]]

def value(v): return v[1]

import itertools
s = sorted(zip(string, a), key=value)
s = ((l, r) for (l, (r, c)) in s)
s = itertools.groupby(s, key=value)
print '\n'.join(''.join(c for (c, r) in g[1]) for g in s)
```

This `zip`s the string with the list which is then `sorted` by the list element then the column is removed and the items are `groupby`ed their row and the each of the letters in each groups is `join`ed after removing their row and then the groups are `join`ed as lines.

which prints:

```
WOEL
HLLOR
```

I don't know where the second `E` disappeared to.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of using a couple of list comprenhension and a zip function.

```
a=[[1,0],[0, 2],[0, 4],[1,1],[0, 1],[0, 0],[1,3],[1,4],[1,2]]
string = "HELLOWORL"
# zip(*a) extracts the first and the last element of each elemnt of a
# in a different list
rows, cols = zip(*a)
# Find the maximum possible value and sum 1in order to use then xrange
maxrow=max(rows) + 1
maxcol=max(cols) + 1
# Create an empty list with placeholders fot he characteres
b=[["" for _ in xrange(maxcol)] for _ in xrange(maxrow)]
for i in xrange(len(string)):
    letter=string[i]
    row,col = a[i]
    # Change the placeholder for the correct character
    b[row][col]=letter
# Paste everything pith join
result = "\n".join(["".join(i) for i in b])
```

Wich results in result ="WOEL\nHLLOR"

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way less elegant than the previous ones from my coleages, much more "wordy", but maybe more accesible to you (you said you were new to python).

```
a=[[1,0],[0, 2],[0, 4],[1,1],[0, 1],[0, 0],[1,3],[1,4],[1,2]]
string = "HELLOWORL"

lista = [[a[i], string[i]] for i in range(0, len(string))]
lista.sort()

coordinate_x = lista[0][0][0]
string = ""
for x in lista:
    if (x[0][0] == coordinate_x):
        string = string + x[1]
    else:
        print string
        string = x[1]
        coordinate_x = x[0][0]
print string
```

I hope it helps you.